# Change base URL of Yoast Sitemap

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

We're using wordpress for our headless CMS and the Yoast plugin to generate sitemaps. However Yoast uses the domain of the site i.e content.domain.com as the base url to generate the links on the sitemap. How can we change this to be the url front end website?

Comment: You'll have to ask Yoast's support team. [Third-party plugin support is off-topic here.](/help/on-topic)

Comment: At a guess, edit the WordPress config settings to tell it what the base domain should be.